# Looking for examples of 3rd-order contact transformations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, contact-geometry

In the [Herglotz Lectures on Contact Transformations and Hamiltonian Systems](https://wydawnictwo.umk.pl/upload/files/OPEN%20ACCESS/LNNA/The%20Herglotz%20lectures%20on%20contact%20transformations%20and%20Hamiltonian%20systems.pdf), after going through contact transformations of the form $X=X(x,y,p)$, $Y=Y(x,y,p)$, $P=P(x,y,p)$ it is stated:

> As a final remark, we note that it is possible to develop a theory for higher order contacts of curves; however, the formulas become unwieldy, and they are difficult to apply in concrete situations.

Are there any references for such a theory or examples of higher order contact transformations? I’m interested specifically in 3rd-order contact transformations of the form  $X=X(x,y,p,u)$, $Y=Y(x,y,p,u)$, $P=P(x,y,p,u)$, $U=U(x,y,p,u)$.

---

I have attempted to come up with some to no avail. As far as I can tell, a 3rd-order contact transformation must satisfy
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{1}
(X_x+pX_y+uX_p)Y_u&=(Y_x+pY_y+uY_p)X_u\quad \text{and}\\
(X_x+pX_y+uX_p)P_u&=(P_x+pP_y+uP_p)X_u,
\end{align}
(with nonzero Jacobian).
The most general solution to the first I can find is $X=X(u,xu-p,x^2u-2xp+2y)$, $Y=Y(u,xu-p,x^2u-2xp+2y)$, but such functions cannot also satisfy the latter.

I have also tried modifying the directrix introduced shortly after in the Herlotz Lectures. The directrix for 2nd-order contact transformations is a function $\Omega(x,y,X,Y)=0$, which together with $\Omega_x+\Omega_yp=0$ and $\Omega_X+\Omega_YP=0$ yields a system of equations which can be solved for $X=X(x,y,p)$, $Y=Y(x,y,p)$, $P=P(x,y,p)$.

A similar directrix of the form $\Omega(x,y,p,X,Y,P)=0$ together with $\Omega_x+\Omega_yp+\Omega_pu=0$ and $\Omega_X+\Omega_YP+\Omega_PU=0$ is short an equation to isolate $X$, $Y$, $P$, and $U$. I’ve also considered directrixes of the form $\Omega(p,xp-y,P,XP-Y)$ together with
\begin{align}
\Omega_1+x\Omega_2&=0,\quad (\Omega_{11}+2x\Omega_{12}+x^2\Omega_{22})u+\Omega_2=0,\\
\Omega_3+X\Omega_4&=0,\quad (\Omega_{33}+2X\Omega_{34}+X^2\Omega_{44})U+\Omega_4=0,
\end{align}
though this has failed to help me produce a 3rd-order contact transformation.

---

*Edit*

A possible 3rd-order contact transformation. Assume that $U=f(x,y,p)$ and denote $D=\partial_x+p\partial_y+u\partial_p$. Then integrating $U=P_u/X_u$ and $P=Y_u/X_u$ we get that
\begin{align}
U=f,\quad P=fX-g,\quad Y=\frac12fX^2-gX-h,
\end{align}
with functions $g=g(x,y,p)$ and $h=h(x,y,p)$.

Upon substituting these candidate transformations into equations \ref{1} we find that
\begin{align}
X=&\frac{Dg}{Df}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\right)^2+2\frac{Dh}{Df}},\\
Y=&\left(f\frac{Dg}{Df}-g\right)\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\right)^2+2\frac{Dh}{Df}}\right)+f\frac{Dh}{Df}-h,
\end{align}
from the first equation and
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\right)^2+2\frac{Dh}{Df}=0
\end{align}
from the second. So any transformation of the form
\begin{align}
X=\frac{Dg}{Df},&\quad Y=\frac{f}{2}\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\right)^2-g\frac{Dg}{Df}-h,\\&P=f\frac{Dg}{Df}-g,\quad U=f,
\end{align}
where $f$, $g$, and $h$ satisfy $\left(\frac{Dg}{Df}\right)^2+2\frac{Dh}{Df}=0$ is a 3rd-order contact transformation. Though, I have been unable to find $f$, $g$, and $h$ which satisfy the final condition, which can be expanded to
\begin{align}
u^2(g_p^2+2f_ph_p)+2u(g_p(pg_y+g_x)+f_p(ph_y+h_x)+h_p(pf_y+f_x))+(pg_y+g_x)^2+2(pf_y+f_x)(ph_y+h_x)=0.
\end{align}